# Why am I getting an additional riser/bar in my chart in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have a chart that looks like this:
[image]

Here is what I have in the chart expert:
[image]

And here is the code for @ZZ_TAT_Name - A:

```
if {IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID} = next({IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID}) and {IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID} = previous({IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID}) then "na" else
IF {@Final Turnaround Minutes} > 0 and {@Final Turnaround Minutes} < 15 THEN "UNDER 15"
ELSE IF {@Final Turnaround Minutes} >= 15 and {@Final Turnaround Minutes} < 30 THEN "BETWEEN 15 & 30"
ELSE IF {@Final Turnaround Minutes} >= 30 and {@Final Turnaround Minutes} < 60 THEN "BETWEEN 30 & 60"
ELSE if {@Final Turnaround Minutes} > 60 then "OVER 60"
//else "*Total Messages"
```

I am wanting to get rid of the riser that shows 11. That riser is the total DistinctCount of IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID. How would I be able to remove this? Why is this even showing up?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've mentioned below, it seems 11 out of 22 records appear to fall into none of the if-else categories, leading to the unlabeled blue column. The easiest way to proceed is to intervene before the chart is rendered and reduce the incoming data to only values that belong in the other columns:

There's a few ways to handle this, but I would recommend adding an intermediary Formula that returns the exact same records, except any record that doesn't meet the if/else standards will be replaced with null. Something like:

```
IF (
    {IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID} = next({IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID})
    AND
    {IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID} = previous({IB_MESSAGES.MSG_ID})
)
OR (
    {@Final Turnaround Minutes} > 0
    AND
    {@Final Turnaround Minutes} > 60
)
THEN
    //repeat the original value here
ELSE
    null
```

Done correctly, the intermediary formula will return 11 records and 11 nulls when evaluated in the Details section of the report. From here, you can change your chart to read the formula and it should evaluate only 11 non-null values.

Comment: I do handle it in my code I just have it commented out at the moment. So, if I uncomment my final else, it just places the string under the bar/riser. I want to get rid of the combined riser/bar.

Comment: In that case you'll want to trick the chart into thinking those 11 values don't exist before the chart is generated. Depending on how everything else is set up you can either filter them out during record selection, evaluate on a new function that ignores them, or place the chart into a more restrictive subreport.